# How to serve static files saved in a docker volume with FastAPI?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, fastapi, docker-volume

I've created two volumes, `t21db` for my SQLite DB and `t21images` for my images, in my FastAPI app im using `app.mount` to mount the location for the volume to retrieve the images, here's the code -

```
app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

app.mount("/app/images", StaticFiles(directory="."), name="static") # <--- here, is this directory correct?

app.include_router(webapp, prefix='/api/v1/webapp', tags=["WebApp"])
app.include_router(webapptype, prefix='/api/v1/webapptype', tags=["WebAppType"])
```

I have an endpoint which uses a function to get the image URL's from the volume but this doesn't seem to be working at the moment as I'm getting a status code 404 back

```
def __get_url(self, image, request: Request):
    return request.url_for('static', path=f"app/images/{image}")
```

this is how I am running my container & mounting volumes to it -

```
docker run --mount source=t21db,target=/app/db --mount source=t21images,target=/app/images -p 3088:5000 t21
```

I was previously using `/app/images` path to retrieve images to encode but later changed that serving the image URL was more efficient

How can I get the correct volume path in my app to serve the static files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the solution is to add the path to the `directory` as the initial path param in `app.mount`

So this worked -

```
app.mount("/app/images", StaticFiles(directory="/apps/images"), name="static")
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope it'll helpfull,

what i using in mine without mounting directory in docker is

```
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
app.mount("/media", StaticFiles(directory="media"), name="media")
```

make sure you set directory correctly

and try

```
app.mount("/images", StaticFiles(directory="images"), name="images")
```

i even used traefik or nginx without mounting my statics or ... folder